# shell_exec question

Tags: php, linux

Say I want to execute an ant command on a linux server using php on a website...

Can I do say, `/home/user/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant compile` - where `compile` is the command?

Basically I need to start up a few things with ANT in a few different directories. I would like to do this from a php webpage, can `shell_exec` perform this?

Comment: Yes. That's what it is for. If it does work on your server is an entirely different question; as it's dependent on the environment / security settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `shell_exec` can run any command (with appropriate permissions).

Comment: sweet, and how to execute it? Does it automatically assume your php file is link to "localhost" or do you have to call on the server and the server user as you would with a db?

Comment: Your PHP code is a program, running on a computer. `shell_exec` is how that PHP program can execute another program, on that same computer. There's no other server involved. If you want to run that ant task, then `shell_exec('/home/user/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant compile');`

Comment: say you were to upload it to a server though.. it would treat that as "localhost"right?

Comment: Then the 'server' is the computer the PHP program is running on, and where the program you want to run with `shell_exec` has to be too. "localhost" is a DNS hostname pointing to the IP address 127.0.0.1, DNS is not involved in what we're talking about.